# Distance between two aruco markers changes at different angles

Tags: python, computer-vision, opencv, aruco

I'm trying to write a program to find the distance between two aruco markers and the distance seems to be about right when the markers are located to the left and right of the camera frame, but when they are located at the top and bottom of the camera frame, the distance between them is totally wrong?

Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import cv2.aruco as aruco

    
def mag(x):
    return np.sqrt(x[0]**2+x[1]**2+x[2]**2)


criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

mtx = np.array([[ 8.8213173810477792e+02, 0., 6.2265593183247574e+02],[ 0.,
       9.0710890795744012e+02, 4.1207655778884924e+02],[ 0., 0., 1. ]])

dist = np.array([ 5.3943178087169294e-03, -2.0750715497990183e-01,
       -1.2051405507801402e-03, -2.0261943010518283e-03,
       4.2906970296298941e-01 ])

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # Get the camera source

alltvec = np.zeros([50,3])

def track(matrix_coefficients, distortion_coefficients):
    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read() #capture a fram
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # Change grayscale
        aruco_dict = aruco.Dictionary_get(aruco.DICT_4X4_50)  # Use 4x4 dictionary to find markers
        parameters = aruco.DetectorParameters_create()  # Marker detection parameters
        
        # lists of ids and the corners beloning to each id
        corners, ids, rejected_img_points = aruco.detectMarkers(gray, aruco_dict,
                                                                parameters=parameters,
                                                                cameraMatrix=mtx,
                                                             distCoeff=dist)

        if np.all(ids is not None):  # If there are markers found by detector
            for i in range(0, len(ids)):  # Iterate in markers
                # Estimate pos of each marker and return the values rvec and tvec---different from camera coefficients
                rvec, tvec, markerPoints = aruco.estimatePoseSingleMarkers(corners[i], 0.031, mtx,dist)
                (rvec - tvec).any()  # get rid of that numpy value array error
                aruco.drawDetectedMarkers(frame, corners)  # Draw A square around the markers
                aruco.drawAxis(frame, matrix_coefficients, distortion_coefficients, rvec, tvec, 0.01)  # Draw Axis
                alltvec[ids[i]-1] = tvec #add tvec value to array of all tvecs
        

        if ids is not None and len(ids) > 0:  # If there are two markers, reverse the second and get the difference
            vector = alltvec[1]-alltvec[0]
            distance = np.linalg.norm(vector)
            cv2.putText(frame, "Distance: {:.2f} m".format(distance), (10, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        
        #Wait 3 milisecoonds for an interaction. Check the key and do the corresponding job.
        key = cv2.waitKey(3) & 0xFF
        if key == ord('q'):  # Quit
            break
    # When everything done, release the capture
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    
track(mtx,dist)
```

[Markers when side to side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbTD2.png)

[Markers when top to bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoOpo.png)

I've tried just getting the distances of the markers from the camera and this seems to be normal regardless of where in the frame the markers are

If it's of any help, the markers on the sheet of paper are 20cm apart in the long direction and 10cm apart in the shorter direction

(their distance apart is about right for when they are side to side but totally off when they are top to bottom of the frame)

Comment: Can you print alltvec[0] and alltvec[1]?  Shouldn't you check for len(ids) > 1 instead of len(ids) > 0?

Comment: How good is your calibration (mtx and dist,)?

Comment: Are you sure these go from 0 to 1? alltvec[ids[i]-1] = tvec why are you using the IDs but not i directly? At the bottom you are using a static 0 and 1 instead of id[0]-1 and id[1]-1

Comment: I've checked by printing the alltvec[0] and alltvec[1], they both have values. Also I've changed the len(ids)>0 to >1 but that hasn't made a difference. Also the reason for using the the alltvec[ids[i]-1] is so that the tvecs will be put into the 'alltvecs' such that they are ordered by their ids. e.g. marker 1 will be at positon 0 and marker 3 will be at position 2.

Comment: I've calibrated the camera using 8 images of a 9x5 chessboard from a script I found online - I could post the code and calibration images I used if that might help diagnose the problem? Thanks for helping

Comment: And the two markers in your image are always markers 1 and 2?

Comment: yep they are. I have worked it out now - I had a really dodgey calibration of my camera. I'm not entirely sure what was wrong with it but it's good now. Thank you for your help :)